# Angular 2 FormGroup Add Validators dynamic

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i'm tring to add validator to FormContol dynamic (not on initialization) and it's not work....

the code:

```html
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].validator = Validators.Required;
```

Did anyone do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators(Validators.required);
```

For multiple validators

```
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]);
```

But doing so will override any validators that are provided during initialization

**EDIT** :

To reflect the form controls with newly added `Validators` immediately, we have to call  `this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity();` after setting validators dynamically.

```
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators(Validators.required);
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity();
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setvalidators?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for the same

*** NOTE ***

updateValueAndValidity() will trigger a valueChanges event even if the value didn't really change (potentially resulting in an infinite loop, if you're calling it from within a valueChanges subscription). You can prevent that by using the optional parameter object: { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false}

Answer (score 6):

While Amit Chigadani's answer is correct, please bear in mind the following.

While this solution works for updating validators, the new validators themselves will not be run, until you change the form fields value. it is thus recommended to run the following function straight after you update you validators ;)

In laymans terms: Add the line, If you want your ng-valid and ng-invalid classes to update themselves.

```
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]);
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity();
```

In case you only want to update the value and validity of this single control, then add this option

```
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]);
this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
```

Another sidenote. In Angular2, one shouldn't use the array syntax to get form group controls, but this

```
this.formGroup.get("firstName");
```

Which also accepts the dot notation

```
this.formGroup.get("userSectionFormGroup.firstName");
```

Comment: Thanks, man!! I was so angry that my submit wouldn't disable after adding a *required* validation! And it wouldn't enable after removing it!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

got the solution we can do with the below code.

```
const validators = new Array<Validators>();
          validations.forEach(validation => {
            switch (validation.Type) {
              case 'required':
                validators.push(Validators.required);
                break;
              case 'minLength':
                validators.push(Validators.minLength(parseInt(validation.Expression, 10)));
                break;
              case 'maxLength':
                validators.push(Validators.maxLength(parseInt(validation.Expression, 10)));
                break;
              case 'pattern':
                validators.push(Validators.pattern(validation.Expression));
                break;
            }
          });
          this.form.controls[i].setValidators(validators);
 }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Very usefull the "pattern" and "max/minLength" example, using ".Expression"! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, "validators" Type should be "ValidatorFn" and not "Validators". ;-)  
At least in Angular V6 - don't know on previous ones, if Validators were already functions...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using:

```
export function getValidatorFnArray(obj): ValidatorFn[] {

  const validators = [];

  if (obj.required || obj.required === '' ) {
    validators.push(Validators.required);
  }
  if (obj.minLength) {
    validators.push(Validators.minLength(parseInt(obj.minLength, 10)));
  }
  if (obj.maxLength) {
    validators.push(Validators.maxLength(parseInt(obj.maxLength, 10)));
  }
  if (obj.pattern) {
    validators.push(Validators.pattern(obj.pattern));
  }
  if (obj.email || obj.email === '') {
    validators.push(Validators.email);
  }

  return validators
}
```

where `obj` could be something like:

```
validation: { 
  required: '',
  pattern: '\d+',
}
```