# Set formvalidator on FormArray for required and minlength

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am looking to set a minlength validator on a formArray element.

Here's how I created the form.

```
this.fb.group({
            FieldName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\S*/)]],
            Treatment: '',
            Properties: this.fb.group(
                {
                    contentType: this.fb.array([]),
                    multipleItems: false,
                    keyType: this.fb.group({
                        'Type': '',
                        'Prefix': '',
                        'Suffix': ''
                    }),
                }
            )
        });
```

This is the code I am trying. It doesn't get applied, and the form totally ignores this and becomes valid.

```
this.fieldForm.get('Properties.contentType').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]);
```

Comment: where do you create the formGroup? can you add the code to the question?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara added.

Comment: is there any specific reason to add setValidators after form control initialize?

Comment: @Chellappan yes, these controls are initialized only if certain value is selected. I don't want the whole form to be invalid if that particular value is not selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 FormGroup Add Validators dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603605/angular-2-formgroup-add-validators-dynamic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `updateValueAndValidity()` after setting new validators

```
this.fieldForm.get('Properties.contentType').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]);
this.fieldForm.get('Properties.contentType').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Also Note that, it has to be `this.fieldForm.get('Properties').get('contentType').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]);`

Because you have child form group for `Properties` control.

Comment: That worked. One quick question. I am trying to apply a class to it when it doesn't meet the requirement. I am testing it like this.
{{this.fieldForm.get('Properties.contentType').hasError('minLength')}} And it shows false.

Comment: Correct the spelling of minlength. all lower case

Comment: still shows false. Even though the form is invalid because it didn't meet the min length requirements. :/

Comment: {{fieldForm.get('Properties.contentType').hasError('minlength')}}

Comment: `Validators.minLength(1)` is equivalent to `Validators.required` because you are checking for `length=1`, So it fires up required error instead. try changing it to some higher value and check.

Comment: You are killing it! Thanks! it worked. I checked the DOM and it was just adding required in the errors.

Comment: Note that, it has to be `this.fieldForm.get('Properties').get('contentType').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]);` Because you have child form group for `Properties` control

Comment: Will do that. I checked the answer as accepted, because he has lesser points, even though both the answers are perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: You should give preference to the one who was quick to answer and solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

`Set` a validator for a control in the `FormGroup`: `this.myForm.controls['controlName'].setValidators([Validators.required])`

`Remove` the validator from the control in the `FormGroup`: `this.myForm.controls['controlName'].clearValidators()`

`Update` the `FormGroup` once you have run either of the above lines. `this.myForm.controls['controlName'].updateValueAndValidity()`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751840/6426617)

So the context

```
    this.fieldForm.controls['Properties.contentType'].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]);
    this.fieldForm.controls['Properties.contentType'].updateValueAndValidity()
```

Comment: That worked. One quick question. I am trying to apply a class to it when it doesn't meet the requirement. I am testing it like this. {{this.fieldForm.get('Properties.contentType').hasError('minLength')}} And it shows false.

Comment: @Aijaz error key is `minlength` not `minLength` so it has to be `.hasError('minlength')`

Comment: still shows false. Even though the form is invalid because it didn't meet the min length requirements. :/

Comment: {{fieldForm.get('Properties.contentType').hasError('minlength')}}

Comment: You are killing it! Thanks! it worked. I checked the DOM and it was just adding required in the errors.