# Apply Angular 6 Compose Validator Conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my application I want to apply compose validator conditionally and respective validators. I did with custom validator but doesn't get success.

```js
this.myForm = this.builder.group({
   country:['',Validators.required],
   age:['',Validators.required],
   dependentName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.required])]
})
```

1. If country is 'America' and age is less than 18 then dependentName is required and max length should be 20.
2. If the country is other than 'America' then dependentName field is not required but maxlength should be 20.

Please help.

Comment: You could add those validators dynamically, based on input value of the country https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603605/angular-2-formgroup-add-validators-dynamic/43604037#43604037

Comment: Can you provide that custom validator that you try to create?

Answer (score 0):

define your custome validator service and use it in formBuilder as given below

```
dependentName: ['',  [Validators.required, customValidationService.checkLimit(1,maxValue)]], /// provide your limit in place of minvalue and maxValue , like checkLimit(1,99)
```

in your **customValidationService **

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class customValidationService {
   static checkLimit(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (c.value && (isNaN(c.value) || c.value < min || c.value > max)) {
            return { 'range': true };
        }
        return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Or

```
dependentName: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10)])]
```