# get hidden input value on click of button in reactive forms angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, hidden-field

I am trying to get values of hidden input which is added dynamically on click of `insert more` button.

Here is stackblitz link: [get hidden input value](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-dynamic-added-component-values-qgky91)

I tried to use `patchValue()` method on `linkTo()` function but no luck, I am getting empty string on click of `Get Values` button in console.

**in console:**

```
loginFromArr: Array[2]
0: Object
name: "p1"
password: "p235"
selectedLinkTo: ""
1: Object
name: "876548"
password: "43545t"
selectedLinkTo: ""
```

here `selectedLinkTo` value is empty.

Comment: Thats because of `<input type="hidden" formControlName="selectedLinkTo" />` has no vlaue even if you click on `getValue button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have try something with code and added the Value in the SelectLinkTo.

```
linkTo(where: string, btnId: number) {
    console.log(btnId);    
    let formArray = (<FormArray>this.loginForm[this.currentTab].get('loginFromArr')).at(btnId)
    console.log(formArray);
    formArray.patchValue({
        selectedLinkTo :where
    })    
}
```

For validation, you can add following code

```
printCurrentTab() {
 if(this.loginForm[this.currentTab].valid) {
  console.log(this.loginForm[this.currentTab].getRawValue());
 }else{
  console.log("Please fill the required fields")
 }
}
```

And for adding new Row add here also

```
addMore() {
  if(this.loginForm[this.currentTab].valid) {
    this.loginFromArr.push(
      this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        password: ["", Validators.required],
        selectedLinkTo: ["", Validators.required]
      })
    );
  } else {
    console.log("Please fill the required fields")
  }
}
```

This will work for the validation.

Comment: Let me try this!

Comment: Sure thing, Let me know if you find any issue.

Comment: Also, is there any way to set validation on that?

Comment: You can add dynamic validation using this `this.formGroup.controls["form Control Name"].setValidators(Validators.required);` . Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/43604037/4452091

Comment: I tried but not working. see this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-dynamic-added-component-values-qgky91

Comment: You have to add the condition in the printCurrentTab() function that `if(this.loginForm[this.currentTab].valid){ //valid } else{ // error message }` Try this

Comment: It's not working for hidden values, otherwise it's ok. See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-dynamic-added-component-values-qgky91

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204338/discussion-between-puneet-sharma-and-pathik-vejani).

Comment: see updated  stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-dynamic-added-component-values-buhchq
added code for `linkTo()`

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass form and set the control value like this.

```
<a style="border: 1px solid red;margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px;" id="a-{{i}}" 
  (click)="linkTo('a',item)" 
   class="btn-link-group border-right-0 first-btn"
mat-button>A link</a>
```

---

```
linkTo(where: string, form: any) {
    //debugger;
    form.controls['selectedLinkTo'].setValue(where);
  }
```

Here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-dynamic-added-component-values-fecshe

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
linkTo(where: string, btnId: number) {
this.loginForm[this.currentTab].get('loginFromArr').controls[btnId].get('selectedLinkTo').setValue(where);}
```

Please replace your linkTo function with above code.

Answer (score 0):

linkTo function patchValue():

```
linkTo(where: string, btnId: number) {
        let formArray = this.loginForm[this.currentTab].get('loginFromArr').at(btnId)
        formArray.patchValue({
            selectedLinkTo :where
        })  
}
```

Checkout Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-dynamic-added-component-values-z4j2si?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts